# Get a color wheel for MLT color grading in Openshot with Movit

Tags: xml, video-processing, mlt

I'm trying to make an effect in openshot for lift-gamma-gain based colorgrading.
I downloaded the latest Movit library and put it on the rigth plaece, MLT and Frei0r is installed and openshot is too. Now i got an XML file (based on [these](http://www.mltframework.org/bin/view/MLT/FilterMovit-lift_gamma_gain) instructions)
that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE openshot-effect>
<effect>
<title translatable="True">Color adjustment</title>
<description translatable="True">Simple color adjustment</description>
<icon>coloradj_RGB.png</icon>
<category>Video</category>
<service>movit.lift_gamma_gain</service>

<param name="lift_r" type="float" title="Lift Red" description="Amount of red in shadows">
    <min>0.0</min>
    <default>0.0</default>
</param>

<param name="ligt_g" type="float" title="Lift Green" description="Amount of green in shadows">
    <min>0.0</min>
    <default>0.0</default>
</param>

<param name="lift_b" type="float" title="Lift Blue" description="Amount of blue in shadows">
    <min>0.0</min>
    <default>0.0</default>
</param>

<param name="gamma_r" type="float" title="Gamma Red" description="Amount of red in midtones">
    <min>0.0</min>
    <default>1.0</default>
</param>

<param name="gamma_g" type="float" title="Gamma Green" description="Amount of green in midtones">
    <min>0.0</min>
    <default>1.0</default>
</param>

<param name="gamma_b" type="float" title="Gamma Blue" description="Amount of blue in midtones">
    <min>0.0</min>
    <default>1.0</default>
</param>

<param name="gain_r" type="float" title="Gain Red" description="Amount of red in highlights">
    <min>0.0</min>
    <default>1.0</default>
</param>

<param name="gain_g" type="float" title="Gain Green" description="Amount of green in highlights">
    <min>0.0</min>
    <default>1.0</default>
</param>


<param name="gain_b" type="float" title="Gain Blue" description="Amount of blue in highlights">
    <min>0.0</min>
    <default>1.0</default>
</param>


</effect>
```

Now i'm trying to get a color wheel as widget in MLT, but the color wheel function as widget is not installed in MLT by default. How can i get the color wheel to appear as widget in Openshot and make this color grading effect functional?

Answer (score 0):

MLT does not provide any widgets. It is only a processing library. It is OpenShot in conjunction with GTK+ that needs to provide the color wheel.
Also, OpenShot does not support Movit effects. Apps that want to use Movit need to provide an OpenGL context as instructed in [this MLT doc](http://www.mltframework.org/bin/view/MLT/OpenGL). However, OpenShot does not provide that.

Answer (score 0):

And this is an example of one of those color wheels, used by Shotcut, i guess? https://github.com/mltframework/shotcut/blob/master/src/widgets/colorwheel.cpp